# Can I print the current readline value after printing other content to the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I have a simple http server that returns a 200 - success response, and a readline function that prints whatever is typed into the terminal.

*Question*: Is there a way to collect what has been typed and reprint it below so the user can continue typing while the server continues serving requests? Or is there a smarter way to combine stdin and stdout in a nodeJS application?

*Explanation*:

The server code:

```
const http = require("http");
const readline = require("readline");

const host = "localhost";
const port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer(async (request, response) => {
  console.log("request received");
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end("success");
});

server.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});

const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin
});

lineReader.on("line", (line) => {
  console.log(`Received ${line}`);
});
```

If I type something into the command line, it works:

```
[~/workspace/tests/async-prompt] node index.js
Listening on 8080
Something
Received Something
```

And if I visit the server, it works:

```
[~/workspace/tests/async-prompt] node index.js
Listening on 8080
request received
```

But if, while I'm typing into the terminal, a request comes in, it gets muddled up:

```
[~/workspace/tests/async-prompt] node index.js
Listening on 8080
typingtypingtypingrequest received
typing
Received typingtypingtypingtyping
```

Is there a way to print what I was in typing when interrupted by something else printing to the output? I would be satisfied with something like this:

```
[~/workspace/tests/async-prompt] node index.js
Listening on 8080
typingtypingtypingrequest received
typingtypingtyping_
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer in this article: [Real Time Chat with NodeJS/Readline/SocketIO](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-readline-socketio--cms-20953). I have to use a helper function to get the current input from the terminal, then clear the line, print the incoming output, then fill the input again:

```
const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: "",
});

const safeLog = (message, ...optionalParams) => {
  const currentlyTyped = lineReader.line;
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
  if (optionalParams.length > 0){
    console.log(message, optionalParams);
  } else {
    console.log(message);
  }
  process.stdout.write(currentlyTyped);
}

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  safeLog("Logging on timeout")
}, 2000);

lineReader.on("SIGINT", () => process.exit());

lineReader.on("line", (line) => {
  safeLog(`Received ${line}`);
});
```

Note that when using readline like this, ctrl-c (or SIGINT) will kill the line reader, but not necessarily the rest of the app, so I added a handler for that.